# How to find $\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \frac{x}{3}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{x-1}$?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, statistics

I am trying to solve a question that goes as such:

The discrete random variable X takes on integer values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... and its probability mass function is given by

$$
P(X = x) = \begin{cases}
      \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{x-1}& x = 1, 2, 3, ... \\
      0 & \text{ otherwise}
    \end{cases} $$

Find $E(2X + 1)$, the expected value of $2X + 1$ to two decimal places.

**You may make use of the following relationship if needed:**

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} ka^k = \frac{a}{(1 - a)^2} \text{ for } |a| < 1 \tag{1}
$$

This is what I did:

$$
\begin{align}
E(2X + 1) &= E(2X) + E(1) \text{ (Expectation of a Sum is the Sum of Expecations)} \\
&= 2E(X) + 1 \text{ (Expectation of Constant Multiple is the Constant Multiple of Expectation)} 
\end{align}
$$

So essentially, all I need to calculate is $E(X)$ and substitute it into $2E(X) + 1$ to get the answer.

That is where I am stuck at.

From the given PMF, I understand that

$$
\begin{align}
E(X) &= \sum{P(x_i)} \cdot x_i \\
&= \sum_{x=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{x-1} \cdot x} \\
&= \sum_{x=1}^{\infty}{\frac{x}{3}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{x-1}}\end{align}
$$

However, I am unsure of how to convert the above expression into that of the expression labelled as (1). (the equation under the bolded sentence)

From using WolframAlpha, I understand that convergence techniques may be used to determine that the summation evaluates to 3, but I'm only a freshman and would like to solve it using the relationship given in the question.

Also, there was an answer to this same question on Chegg that said

"The given Probability distribution function corresponds to Geometric Distribution with parameter p =1/3

Thus, E(X) = 1/p = 3"

Could I ask if this answer is accurate, and if so, how does the PDF correspond to a Geometric Distribution? From my study notes, a Geometric Distribution models the number of trials needed to happen until success occurs - how does this tie in to the given PDF in the question?

Sorry for the barrage of questions - but primarily, my issue lies with trying to use the given relationship $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} ka^k = \frac{a}{(1 - a)^2}$ on my $\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}{\frac{x}{3}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{x-1}}$ in order to find $E(X)$ and hence ultimately $E(X + 2)$.

Thank you so much to whoever stumbles upon my question and wants to help.

Comment: $\sum \frac x 3(\frac 2 3)^{x-1}=\frac 1  2\sum x(\frac 2 3)^{x}$

Comment: Ugh I don't know how I missed this - thank you so much @geetha290krm, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it needs no more answer than the first comment.